# Timepicker from JQuery doesn't show up

Tags: php, jquery, css, datetimepicker

Maybe someone already had the problem like mine - I want to use the Simple init DateTimePicker from this [example](http://www.jqueryrain.com/?lnsG0UbP) . I created a simple php page:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.datetimepicker.css" />
<script>
jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="datetimepicker" type="text" >
</body>
</html>
```

I also put the *jquery.datetimepicker.js* and *jquery.js* in the js folder, same with css, however after refreshing the page - all I see is the empty input field and the datepicker doesn't show up. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use $ in place of jQuery

Comment: did u got any error in console ?

Comment: Add your code in `$(function( ... ){});` **[Dom Ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)** event. The Document should be ready when your jQuery code fires.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `document.ready` function and make sure js are included correctly

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, it solved the problem! Do you maybe know also how can I pass the chosen date further (e.g. to some php variable, just to insert it later to the database)?

Comment: To be honest, I'm just starting my adventure with jquery... I used php a lot in case of mysql connections, but if you can recommend me a better way in jquery, then for sure I'm willing to try it :)